# Releasing PendingIntent after reentering app

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Anyone knows how could I cancel PendingIntent after leaving app with Back button? When PendingIntent is switched on and canceled on one session without exiting app in between then it's all fine - I got it covered, but when I leave and reenter I can't anymore cancel it and I have to wait for the alarm.

MainActivity:

```
b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setCall(12000);
                pendingIntent.cancel();
                if (alarmManager!= null) {
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                }
            }
        });

public void setCall(int timeToCall){
    if (alarmManager!= null) {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
    String name = e1.getEditableText().toString();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThisBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    intent.putExtra("name",name);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeToCall, pendingIntent);
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");

    Intent i = new Intent(context, CallScreen.class);
    i.setClassName("(package)", "(classname)");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra("name2", name);
    context.startActivity(i);
    Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cancel PendingIntent after your activity is destroyed (actually after losing a reference to original PendingIntent object), you need to recreate that object in the same way and cancel it.

Therefore, create an object of PendingIntent before trying to cancel it.
Also, you could call cancel directly on PendingIntent object.

Comment: Could You be so kind to explain it more thoroughly?

Comment: From google doc:
A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.

Comment: In your code, you are checking if alarmManager is not null, which will always be true when calling this method for the first time.

So create the object of PendingIntent before you want to either cancel, or pass it to AlarmManager.

Comment: It appears to be working fine right now. I don't know why I have to create the same exact PendingtIntent, but I will do it Your way since it's working :) Could You briefly say what You had in mind saying "pass it to AlarmManager"? For future purposes :) Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Glad to help. Think of it like a tokens, you create it again with same parameters, so you are pointing to same object in the system.

By passing to AlarmManager I thought alarmManager.set(*, pendingIntent)